# JavaScript, LWC, Searching after User to stop typing, debounce

Tags: javascript, input, salesforce, debouncing, lwc

In input user writes a search phrase for searching products. And I would like to set searching after user stopped typing.
[Here](https://schier.co/blog/wait-for-user-to-stop-typing-using-javascript) is a nice example, but not works in Lightning Web Components.
When I begin to write to the search input, there is an [error](https://pasteboard.co/JX8qqfW.png): "This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it."

productList.html:

```
<lightning-input
  type="search"
  class="slds-var-m-bottom_small"
  value={searchKey}
  placeholder="Searching..."
  onchange={handleSearchEvent}>
</lightning-input>
```

productList.js:

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import findProducts from '@salesforce/apex/ProductMaster.findProducts';

export default class ProductList extends LightningElement {
  searchKey = '';
  timeout = null;

  @wire(findProducts, { searchKey: '$searchKey' })
  products;

  handleSearchEvent(event) {
    const eventValue = event.target.value;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function (eventValue) {
      this.searchKey = eventValue;
      console.clear();
      console.log('handleSearchEvent() -> this.searchKey: ' + this.searchKey);
    }, 1000); // searching after 1s
  }
}
```

How is it needed to set timeout?
And js console writes:

```
console.log('handleSearchEvent() -> this.searchKey: ' + this.searchKey);
```

`handleSearchEvent() -> this.searchKey: undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `this` binding in your function needs to be explicitly set:

```
timeout = setTimeout(function (eventValue) {
      this.searchKey = eventValue;
      console.clear();
      console.log('handleSearchEvent() -> this.searchKey: ' + this.searchKey);
    }.bind(this), 1000);
```

But perhaps an easier way would be to just use an arrow function which will implicitly bind `this` I believe:

```
timeout = setTimeout((eventValue) => {
      this.searchKey = eventValue;
      console.clear();
      console.log('handleSearchEvent() -> this.searchKey: ' + this.searchKey);
    }, 1000);
```